# Is it impossible for a quantifier-free formula to contain free variables?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

A first-order language must specify its signature to fix its alphabet of non-logical symbols. A signature $\Sigma$ contains the set $\Sigma^F$ of function symbols and the set $\Sigma^P$ of predicate symbols. Function symbols of arity 0 are called constants and predicate symbols of arity 0 are called propositional variables.

However, there exists another concept 'variable'. Some people say that variables are the technical tool for schematization. I don't understand where is the difference between constant and variable and discussions of variables are often involved with quantifiers. Can we say it is impossible for a quantifier-free formula to contain free variables?

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 5):

First-order formulae con contain free variables, like :

> $x < 1$

or not.

Formulae without free variables are called *sentences* (or *closed* formulae) and they can have **no** occurrences of variables at all, like :

> $0 < 1$

or all occurrences of variables are bounded by quantifiers, like :

> $\exists x (x < 1)$.

The first two formuale above are both quantifier-free; the first one : $x < 1$, has a free occurrence of the variable $x$, while the second one : $0 < 1$, has no occurrences of variables at all.

> Thus, it is possible for a quantifier-free formula to contain free variables.

Comment: However, in formula $x < 1$, $x$ can also be regarded  as a constant. $x=0$ is a possible interpretation of $x$. I don' know the difference between constant and free variable.

Comment: @cxcfan - NO; *constant* and *variables* are different "types" of symbols of the language: the set of constants has no intersection with the set of variables of the language. Variables are always present while constant not necessarily; in the first-order language for arithmetic usually we have one constant : $0$; sometimes two : $0,1$.

Comment: The *interpretation* of the language assign "meaning" to the symbols; it assigns a reference to the constants (if any): e.g. the number *zero* to the symbol $0$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! And one more question: how about the signature of EUF theory(Equality logic with uninterpreted functions)? Uninterpreted functions such as $f_1$, $f_2$ are in the set $\Sigma^F$?

Comment: @cxcfan - I'm not familiar with EUF theory; I've found only this [paper](http://fm.csl.sri.com/SSFT12/smt-euf-arithmetic.pdf). "By definition" the symbols (predicate, constant and function symbols) are part of the language. The *interpretation* of a language is a mapping of the symbols in a "universe" : constants are mapped to elements of the universe, predicates to subset of the universe, function to "operations" in the universe (like the sum : $+ : N \times N \to N$).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!